# Want a servlet to run and change url if login failed

Tags: jsp, servlets, requestdispatcher

I have created a Login page in JSP in which I have simply created a form that asks user for username and password and with the `post` method I called a servlet. Now if the login fails, I want to be redirected to the login page again. For that I can do 2 things:

1. use `forward` method of request dispatcher, or
2. use the `sendRedirect` method.

In the first case, I go back to login page successfully, but the URL is still that of servlet (I don't know how and why) and in the second case, I got the login page as well, but this time the request object will be regenerated (a new one). I don't want a new request object. What can I do?

Comment: Pick one and fix it so it works the way you want. The URL is still the servlet because you forwarded--the URL doesn't change. Why don't you want a new request? Why does it matter what the URL is?

Comment: @DaveNewton actually while in servlet, I am setting a request Parameter that I want to use in login.jsp when returned the control. If a new request is generated then, that parameter would be null. I can't use session object to set the parameter because no session will be created until the login is successful

Answer (score 2):

First a redirect and a forward are really different animals even if both lead to displaying a new page:

- a forward just passes control to another servlet in same request, so the URL in browser cannot change
- a redirect returns a special response asking the browser to issue a new request to the URL passed in the response

Anyway, this is a common use case and there are two common ways to solve it using redirect:

- pass a parameter in the URL: instead of redirecting to `/login`, redirect to `/login?param=value`. That way you can test for existence of this parameter and process it accordingly
- use a session parameter. You **can** create a session before login, simply you shall not set any user id there before login and on successful login you must invalidate previous session and create a new one. This latter way avoids showing the parameter in browser URL and also allow any (Serializable) object instead of being restricted to strings.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should analyze the flow of your request. When you type in the URL of your JSP page e.g. `http://localhost:8080/login.jsp`, your browser sends a `GET` request to your server (say Tomcat). Tomcat finds the JSP page (let's not look at the complicated details), interprets it (since it is a JSP page) and sends an HTML page back to the browser. Nothing changes as far as the URL is concerned: you asked for a JSP page and you get it back. The URL remains at `http://localhost:8080/login.jsp`.

The HTML that browser displays is what `login.jsp` contained: a login form.

The login form, when submitted, results in a [standard HTTP POST behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_(HTTP)) and since you specified (e.g. in the `action` parameter of the HTML form) the browser performs an `HTTP POST` of the form data to your servlet's URL. This URL was something for which you provided a URL mapping for, say `http://localhost:8080/login`. Note that when you pressed the `login` button on the form, the URL was changed by the browser, indicating to you, the user, that it is performing an `HTTP POST` to the servlet's URL.

Now, if you chose to `forward` this request to somewhere else, the URL is untouched because you, as a programmer, chose to serve the `POST` request sent to your servlet (`http://localhost:8080/login`) in some part of your webapp. The returned response is simply displayed by the browser without having any references to the URL. This is exactly what you told it to do. Presumably, you interpreted the `login.jsp` in your `forward` method and that created the login form in the returned HTML. As a result, you had the login form being displayed whereas the URL was still pointing to your servlet. Therefore, while using forward you need to be aware of the URL impact of your forwarding.

Sending a redirect to the `login.jsp` in case of a *failed* login would be the correct thing to do. Again follow the flow of your request. The failed login will be handled on `HTTP POST` to your servlet URL. The `form data` is invalid (e.g. wrong password) and hence your servlet code should send an `HTTP Redirect` which reinstates the correct URL's. This is because when a redirect is sent, what is actually sent is an [HTTP 302](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) response with a `Location` header which tells the browser to go fetch that URL. Since your `Location` header (in case of a failed login) would be that of your JSP page (`login.jsp`), the URL will be pointing to that of the HTML form. Now the URL's start making sense again.

Out of the three scopes in a webapp: request scope, session scope and application scope, request scope is, as the name suggests, for each HTTP request. All the `objects` associated with a request scope get a new value for each request. This is very important to preserve the stateless nature of HTTP.